# alignment of the text inside the container

Tags: html, css

[Updated image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqBzp.png)I have designed a container and it contains different sections so when i try to align the text and data inside it it goes down and not in the div. So I have tried but I don't know what is causing this kind of error...The company name and other details goes down or out of the div bar...
How to do that so the company name which is inside h1 tag and the data below in p tag is displayed in same div.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="home2.css">
    
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<style>
#container {
    background-color: darkgreen;
    height: 350px;
    width: 400px;
    border-style: solid ;
    border-color: #787878;
}

#containerhead {
    height: 10%;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}

#containerbottom {
    height: 20%;
    background-color: white;
    bottom: 0;
}

#containercenter {
    height: 70%;
}
/*/*/*/*/*/
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
    
}
.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.dropbtn {
    height: 36px;
    width: 36px;
}

#pagedesc {
    height: 30%;
    background-color: bisque;
}

#pagedetails {
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: white;
}


#companyico {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 90%;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    width:auto;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="containerhead">
        
        <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">
      <i class="material-icons">more_horiz</i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Option 1</a>
      <a href="#">Option 2</a>
      <a href="#">Option 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
        </div>
        <div id="containercenter">
        <div id="pagedesc">
            <div id="pagedetails"><img id="companyico" src="Logo.jpg" alt="pagelogo"><div id="deta"><h3>Company name</h3><p>123456 apps</p></div>
            <span id="btn"></span>
            </div></div>
        <div id="postdetails">
            
        </div>  
        
        
        </div>
        <div id="containerbottom">
            
        
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide a picture on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: They both are displayed in the div. Do you mean how you can put them in the same line? Both h3 and p tags are blocks, which means they will push the other elements to a new line. You would either need to float them or set display to inline-block on both the h3 and p-tag.

Comment: yes I have updated the post with the image that i want to achieve as output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change their `display` property to make in inline. In the below solution, I've used `flex` to make them inline. There are other ways also to make them inline.
You can read more about flexbox here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />

    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <style>
      #container {
        background-color: darkgreen;
        height: 350px;
        width: 400px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #787878;
      }

      #containerhead {
        height: 10%;
        background-color: antiquewhite;
      }

      #containerbottom {
        height: 20%;
        background-color: white;
        bottom: 0;
      }

      #containercenter {
        height: 70%;
      }
      /*/*/
      */*/*/
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
      }
      .dropdown-content a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
      }
      .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        z-index: 1;
      }

      .dropdown {
        float: right;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .dropdown-content a {
        float: none;
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
      }
      .dropbtn {
        height: 36px;
        width: 36px;
      }

      #pagedesc {
        height: 30%;
        background-color: bisque;
      }

      #pagedetails {
                display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        height: 100%;
        width: 80%;
        background-color: white;
      }

      #companyico {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 90%;
        padding-left: 6px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        width: auto;
      }

      #deta {
        display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        margin-left: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="containerhead">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">
            <i class="material-icons">more_horiz</i>
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Option 1</a>
            <a href="#">Option 2</a>
            <a href="#">Option 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="containercenter">
        <div id="pagedesc">
          <div id="pagedetails">
            <img id="companyico" src="/src/logo.jpg" alt="pagelogo" />
            <div id="deta">
              <h3>Company name</h3>
              <p>123456 apps</p>
            </div>
            <span id="btn"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="postdetails"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="containerbottom"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. More cleaner version of your code.

I have added a `div` to bring your `img` and company together also use `display:flex`

Run snippet below.

```css
#container {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  height: 350px;
  width: 400px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #787878;
}

#containerbottom {
  height: 20%;
  bottom: 0;
}

#containercenter {}


/*/*/

*
/*/*/

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropbtn {
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
}

#pagedesc {
  height: 30%;
  background-color: bisque;
}

#pagedetails {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

#companyico {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 90%;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  width: auto;
}

#deta {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="home2.css">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="containerhead">

      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">
      <i class="material-icons">more_horiz</i>
    </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Option 1</a>
          <a href="#">Option 2</a>
          <a href="#">Option 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="containercenter">
      <div id="pagedesc">
        <div id="pagedetails">
          <div id="deta">
            <img id="companyico" src="Logo.jpg" alt="pagelogo">
            <div id="details">
              <h3>Company name</h3>
              <p>123456 apps</p>
            </div>


          </div>
          <span id="btn"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="postdetails">

      </div>


    </div>
    <div id="containerbottom">


    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: upvoting answer this too. flex is best way to do.

Comment: Its helping community. Appreciating for helping. Welcome

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to using `float:left`

```css
#container {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  height: 350px;
  width: 400px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #787878;
}

#containerhead {
  height: 10%;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

#containerbottom {
  height: 20%;
  background-color: white;
  bottom: 0;
}

#containercenter {
  height: 70%;
}


/*/*/

*
/*/*/

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropbtn {
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
}

#pagedesc {
  height: 30%;
  background-color: bisque;
}

#pagedetails {
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: white;
}

#companyico { 
    height: 43%;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-top: 5px; 
    float: left;
    width: 22%;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
#deta{
    float: left;  
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="home2.css">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="containerhead">

      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">
      <i class="material-icons">more_horiz</i>
    </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Option 1</a>
          <a href="#">Option 2</a>
          <a href="#">Option 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="containercenter">
      <div id="pagedesc">
        <div id="pagedetails"><img id="companyico" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="pagelogo">
          <div id="deta">
            <h3>Company name</h3>
            <p>123456 apps</p>
          </div>
          <span id="btn"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="postdetails">

      </div>


    </div>
    <div id="containerbottom">


    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```